# I'm trying to access data through pointers and 2D arrays, but I'm getting bus error, does anyone know why this is the case?

Tags: c, pointers

The code was mostly given to me by my lecturer. Ignore the free2DF function. The issue is that on the second iteration of the outer loop the bus error occurs and the program terminates, and I'm not really sure why. I'm trying to give values to the first 2 matrices and then add them for the third index by index. Any explanation or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float **alloc2Df(int height, int width);
void free2DF(float **matr);

int main(void)
{
   int height = 4, width = 4, i, j;
   float **matr1, **matr2, **matr3;

   matr1 = alloc2Df(height, width);
   matr2 = alloc2Df(height, width);
   matr3 = alloc2Df(height, width);

   for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
   {
       printf("%d\n", i*width);
      for(j = 0; j < height; j++)
      {
         **(matr1+(i*width)+j) = 1;
     **(matr2+(i*width)+j) = 2;
     **(matr3+(i*width)+j) = **(matr1+(i*width)+j) + **(matr2+(i*width)+j);

     printf("%-5.1f", **(matr3+(i*width)+j));
      }

      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}

float **alloc2Df( int height, int width ) 
{    
   int i;    
   int nelem;    
   float *p, **pp;        

   nelem = height * width;    
   p = (float*)calloc( nelem, sizeof(float) );    
   if( p == NULL )            
      return NULL; 

   pp = (float**)calloc( height, sizeof(float*) );    
   if( pp == NULL )      
   {         
      free(p);         
      return NULL;     
   }      

   for ( i=0; i<height; i++ )      
      pp[i] = p + i*width;       

   return pp; 
   } 

void free2Df( float **matr ) 
{
   if( matr != NULL ) free( (float*) *matr );    
      free((float**) matr);        

   return; 
}
```

Comment: Try to explain for this `pp[i] = p + i*width; ` - where is `pp[i]`? Was it allocated? And where does point `p + i*width`? Was it also allocated? (I am talking about function `float **alloc2Df( int height, int width )`)

Comment: Most likely you are assigning a value to a pointer as an address, resulting in an invalid address pointing to a memory location "way way down in the system-reserved address space" which results in a bus-error.

Comment: These are not 2D arrays, only emulations for it. Your teacher needs to take a time warp of 30 years. Proper 2D arrays are much simpler to handle and more efficient. There is no excuse to use such legacy code in modern C, and there is even less excuse to teach that, still.

Answer (score 0):

`**(matr1+(i*width)+j)` makes no sense.

`alloc2Df(height, width)` returns a dynamic array `m` of size `height`. Each element `m[i]` is a pointer to the first element of a `float` array of size `width`. (Special consideration: All `m[i]` point into different chunks of the same big `float` array, but that doesn't matter for element access.)

Here's a diagram showing `matr1 = alloc2Df(3, 4)`:

```
matr1
 |
 v
[ ]----------------------->[0.0]
[ ]--------                [0.0]
[ ]--      \               [0.0]
     \      \              [0.0]
      \      ------------->[0.0]
       \                   [0.0]
        \                  [0.0]
         \                 [0.0]
          ---------------->[0.0]
                           [0.0]
                           [0.0]
                           [0.0]
```

As long as `i` is `0` (the first iteration of the outer loop), we're just accessing `**(matr1 + j)` (where `j` goes from `0` to `2`):

```
matr1 --------v
matr1 + 0 -->[ ]----------------------->[1.0] X
matr1 + 1 -->[ ]--------                [0.0]
matr1 + 2 -->[ ]--      \               [0.0]
                  \      \              [0.0]
                   \      ------------->[1.0] X
                    \                   [0.0]
                     \                  [0.0]
                      \                 [0.0]
                       ---------------->[1.0] X
                                        [0.0]
                                        [0.0]
                                        [0.0]
```

`matr1 + j` results in a pointer to one of the elements in the first array (shown on the left above). Dereferencing it with `*` gives us the array element itself, which is another pointer; dereferencing that (with `*` again) sends us to one of the `float`s over on the right (marked `X`).

This is all fine so far.

However, in the second iteration of the outer loop `i` is `1`. The pointers we compute from `matr1 + i*width + j` are therefore `matr1 + 4 + 0`, `matr1 + 4 + 1`, `matr1 + 4 + 2` (because `width = 4`, `height = 3` in this example).

```
matr1 --------v
matr1 + 0 -->[ ]----------------------->[1.0]
matr1 + 1 -->[ ]--------                [0.0]
matr1 + 2 -->[ ]--      \               [0.0]
                  \      \              [0.0]
matr1 + 4 --> ?    \      ------------->[1.0]
matr1 + 5 --> ?     \                   [0.0]
matr1 + 6 --> ?      \                  [0.0]
                      \                 [0.0]
                       ---------------->[1.0]
                                        [0.0]
                                        [0.0]
                                        [0.0]
```

Two things stand out:

1. `matr1 + 3` is never computed. This is probably a bug in the logic. (If our example had `height > width`, this would leave a "negative gap"; i.e. instead of skipping over elements, it would access the same elements twice.)
2. `matr1 + 4` points past the end of the array on the left. In fact, all pointers `matr1 + i*width + j` point who-knows-where if `i > 0`. I'm not surprised that taking an invalid pointer, dereferencing it (`*`), then taking whatever value was found in memory as another pointer and dereferencing that again (`*`), causes a crash.

---

There's a simple fix:

```
matr1[j][i]
```

Or, if you want to use `*` manually:

```
*(*(matr1 + j) + i)
```

There's no need to multiply anything. You're not trying to emulate access to a 2D array given a big 1D array; what you have is already a two-level structure where the first level contains the correct precomputed offsets in the second level array.

`matr1[j]` (or `*(matr1 + j)`) is a pointer to the right chunk within the second array. Applying `[i]` (or `*(... + i)`) to that gives you the right element within the chunk.